# Does Tomcat occasionally redeploy WARs on its own?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, war

I have a webapp that is deployed as a WAR file to a Tomcat 6 server.  It stores some data in a directory inside the app itself.  These files get overwritten when a new version of the app is deployed, but it's trivial to back them up and re-add them.

However, one of my coworkers claims that Tomcat will sometimes spontaneously re-explode my WAR file, even if the exploded version is already there, and wipe out these files.  I have never seen this behavior before.  I can figure out a workaround for this if I really have to, but is this something that actually happens, either spontaneously or on server restart?

Comment: I'll be as interested as you to see if someone has a definitive answer. But I've never observed it to happen. I had a co-worker who was in the habit of modifying config files in WEB-INF after deployment rather than updating the WAR and redeploying, and over the space of several years I never saw these config files magically revert to what was in the WAR.

Comment: Right?  I'm hard-pressed to figure out a situation where Tomcat would actually want to do this if the app and WAR are both there

Comment: If the *last modified date* of the war file is changed, Tomcat might redeploy the application (depending on the configuration). I think that by default it does redeploy the app. If you want to try this on a a linux box, run `touch site.war` and see if Tomcat re-explodes the app.

Comment: @Augusto: Yes, that's true. I have sometimes touch'ed a WAR file to force a re-deploy. And of course if you drop a new WAR file on the server it will re-deploy. But I don't think that qualifies as "spontaneously".

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  And yes, by "spontaneous" I mean without my permission or intervention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tomcat will only autodeploy without restart whenever you have

```xml
<Host autoDeploy="true">
```

in your `/conf/server.xml` and you edit one of the resources in the expanded WAR. But this setting is not really recommended for production environments as it may lead to [memory leaks](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/OutOfMemory). This is also by default turned off.

That said, I strongly recommend to put that data you're talking about outside the WAR. If they are supposed to be part of the webapp's runtime classpath, just put them in a fixed disk file system path outside Tomcat, e.g. `/var/webapp/config` and edit the `shared.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties` to specify that path:

```
shared.loader = /var/webapp/config
```

Those resources will then be available in the classpath the usual way. This way you don't need to backup and re-add it, which is plain clumsy and very error prone.

Comment: "Other than that, Tomcat will always redeploy the WARs on restart."  Do you mean when I restart the server process with `startup.sh`, or when the machine itself restarts?  Because I've tested `startup.sh` several times with no data loss, and I've even done so after `kill`ing the process because it became unresponsive.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, Tomcat 6 will first check the timestamp of the WAR. I must have confused it with older Tomcat or JBoss versions. I removed the incorrect paragraph.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification.  The resources I'm concerned about are basically just CSV files that hold on to some user input, so I don't need to worry about adding them to the classpath.  I'm pretty much just being lazy here, I admit it.